# Accordion not working with IE8

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

The following HTML works in Firefox and Google Chrome. But, it does not work with Internet Explorer 8. The panels would not expand (see code below).

Is there anyway I can make it work with IE8?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>
     Test
    </title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src=" http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
     .custom {
      width: 130px !important;
     }

     div.panel {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: lightblue;
     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="accordion" id="myAccordion">
      <div class="panel">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary custom" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-1" data-parent="#myAccordion">Section 1</button>
      <div id="collapsible-1" class="collapse">
       Content
      </div>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="panel">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary custom" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-2" data-parent="#myAccordion">Section 2</button>
       <div id="collapsible-2" class="collapse">
        Content
       </div>
      </div>
      <br/>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to let us know what you have tried. What happens in IE8? Etc. Be more specific.

Comment: As I have mentioned, it works with Firefox and Chrome, but in IE8, clicking a button won't open its target

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the way you are doing it is not working on IE. I tested the code directly from jqueryui that you can find [here](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible) and it's working for me.
You can also try to change the compatibility with `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />` and try different versions but I don't think that's the best way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply